# Approve Exchange Moderated Messages from iPhone / iPad

Tags: exchange, iphone, outlook-web-app, ipad, safari

We are using SBS 2012. we use email message approval process which works fine on desktop PCs. But when we try to access it from iPad/iPhone's Safari browser, the approve / decline buttons are not shown. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moderated message transport is possible using Outlook or OWA as clients. You cannot do this using iPhone/iPad or any other Exchange ActiveSync based clients.
Hence no Approve/Disapprove buttons for iPhone/iPad

You have to ask the end user to use OWA in iPad for message approval.

Microsoft's guidance here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/06/10/3407662.aspx